# Explanation of the Function that Defines strlen

Tags: c++, strlen

I'm learning about pointers in c++.

I have researched and found the manual function that defines strlen to be something like this.

```
int strlen(const char *a){
    const char *b;
    for (b=a;*b;++b);
    return b-a;
}
```

Would anyone be able to explain this block of code in plain english? In particular, why is *b set as the terminating condition in the for loop?

This is not an answer to homework. It's just a question that arose while I was researching. Thanks.

Comment: `*b` as a condition is the same as `*b != '\0'`, meaning while `b` does not point to the string terminator, or for all characters in the string.

Comment: `strlen` accepts null-terminated string and condition `*b` will become false when the end of string is reached. you can rewrite it as `if('\0' == *b) {break;}`

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Your code is C. You need to spend more time reading about C. `*b` is dereferencing the `b` pointer. When the `char` it points to is 0, it becomes false.

Comment: You might like to read on C-"strings" aka `null`/`NUL`/`0`-terminated `char`-arrays.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This code is also C++.

Comment: It is certainly not genuine C++11, it is C-like disguised as C++

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is 100% genuine C++11.

Comment: The "real" `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particularly terse piece of C code, with a `for` loop that does not have a body.

The idea is to set pointer `b` to the beginning of the string `a`, and keep advancing it until you hit character `'\0'`, which indicates the end of the stirng (i.e. serves as null terminator). Nothing else needs to be done in that loop, hence its body is empty.

Once the loop is over, subtracting `a` from `b` yields the number of characters between the initial character of the string and its null terminator, i.e. the length of the string.

Here is a more readable way to write the same loop:

```
for (b=a ; *b != '\0' ; ++b) // Use explicit comparison to zero
    ;                        // Put semicolon on a separate line
```

When C expression is used in a statement that requires a logical expression, an implicit comparison to zero is applied. Hence, `*b != '\0'` is the same as `*b`.

Answer (score 2):

In both C and C++ strings are really called ***null terminated*** *byte strings*. That *null terminator* is equal to zero. And in both C and C++ the value zero is equivalent to false.

What the loop does is to iterate until the "current character" (pointed to by `b`) becomes equal to the terminator.

Comment: In addition, in genuine C++11, better use `std::string` for strings

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : The "11" modifier is probably irrelevant - the point stands in any edition of the language standard.  That said null-terminated strings and `std::strlen()` exist in the C++; it is no less "genuine C++" for using them.  In fact C++11 _extends_ the C string handling functions with `std::strlen_s()` for example.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: thanks it was hard to choose which of these answers was better, but you did also answer my question.